# PHP date mark current date

Tags: php, date

I have a function that returns a certain date format in a foreach loop. This is how it looks.

```
Wed 17-05

Thu 18-05

Fri 19-05

Sat 20-05

Sun 21-05
```

As you can see the current day appears in the middle. 
This is my code:

```
for ($i = 2; $i > -3; $i--)

{
    echo '<li>'.date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')) . '</li>'.'<br />';

}
```

what i want to achieve is, i want to give the middle day a special color. 
example:

Wed 17-05

Thu 18-05

> Fri 19-05

Sat 20-05

Sun 21-05

All the days appear in an `<li>` can i get the middle day to appear in an li with a distinct class so i can style it in my css?

Comment: try my updated code @Kevin.a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **date('D d-m')** if the date is current date echo add the `class="distinct"`

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 2; $i > -3; $i--)
    { 
        $class="";

        if(date('D d-m')==date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')))
        { 
          $class=' calss="distinct"'; 
        }

        echo '<li'.$class.'>'.date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')) . '</li>'.'<br />';

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: glad to help you @Kevin.a

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 2; $i > -3; $i--)
{
    if($i == 0){
      $active = 'active';
    }

    echo '<li class=".$active.">'.date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')) . '</li>'.'<br />';    
}
```

Write a class in your css, is ok?

Comment: this gives a variable active to every day